# Terminal Value from a to C using VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet name as `Terminal Volumes` In this sheet, there are three variables (`Terminal` `LF (log Fisher Cost)` and `CT Cost`) that are using as input. I am using the following code for working on these.

```
enter code here
Sub InitiateValues()
ReDim TrmPnts(11) '<<<<CHANGE HERE Total Point + SE -JJ
Set ShDat = Worksheets("Data")
Set ShDatPth = Worksheets("DataPath")
Set tvol = Worksheets("Terminal Volumes")
'ShDatPth.Range("B2:FB157").Value = 0
With TrmPnts(1)
    .Cpt = "T1"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(2, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(3, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(2, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(2, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(3)
    .Cpt = "T2"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(6, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(7, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(3, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(3, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(4)
    .Cpt = "T3"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(8, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(9, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(4, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(4, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(5)
    .Cpt = "T4"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(10, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(11, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(5, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(5, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(6)
    .Cpt = "T5"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(12, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(13, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(6, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(6, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(7)
    .Cpt = "T6"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(14, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(15, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(7, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(7, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(8)
    .Cpt = "T7"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(16, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(17, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(8, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(8, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(9)
    .Cpt = "T8"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(18, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(19, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(9, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(9, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(10)
    .Cpt = "T9"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(20, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(21, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(10, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(10, 3)
End With
With TrmPnts(11)
    .Cpt = "T10"
    .CptColr = "&H000088"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(22, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(23, 1)
    .LFamt = tvol.Cells(11, 2)
    .CTamt = tvol.Cells(11, 3)
End With '<<<<<<CHANGE HERE
With TrmPnts(2)
    .Cpt = "SE"
    .CptColr = "&H004400"
    .Row = ShDat.Cells(4, 1)
    .Col = ShDat.Cells(5, 1)
End With
ReDim Mtx(156, 157) ' Cell Size X,Y -JJ
For i = 1 To 156 ' Cell Size X,Y -JJ 1 To 226
    For j = 1 To 157 ' Cell Size X,Y -JJ
        Mtx(i, j) = ShDat.Cells(1 + i, 1 + j)
        ShDatPth.Cells(1 + i, 1 + j) = 0
    Next
Next
EdtMod = True
End Sub
```

This code working fine to input the value to T10 (Only for 10 Rows). I want to use it for T1500 (1500 Rows) for the Column A to Column C- using loop.

The structure of the worksheet is as under.

[image]

Comment: Anyone can do this using For loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `For...next` loop and use the variable of the loop to calculate the correct fields like the following (I hope I interpreted the logic correctly, please check):

```
Sub InitiateValues()
ReDim trmpnts(11) '<<<<CHANGE HERE Total Point + SE -JJ
Set ShDat = Worksheets("Data")
Set ShDatPth = Worksheets("DataPath")
Set tvol = Worksheets("Terminal Volumes")
'ShDatPth.Range("B2:FB157").Value = 0
Dim I As Long
For I = 1 To UBound(trmpnts)
    With trmpnts(I)
        .Cpt = "T" & I
        .CptColr = "&H000088"
        .Row = ShDat.Cells(I * 2, 1)
        .Col = ShDat.Cells(I * 2 + 1, 1)
        .LFamt = tvol.Cells(I, 2)
        .CTamt = tvol.Cells(I, 3)
    End With
Next I
....
End Sub
```

That should do the trick...

Comment: #Jochen I checked this but it giving an error of "Object Required" for the ".Cpt = "T" & I" line of code.

Comment: You didn't write anything about that object and where you define it. I just left that line(s) the way they where instead of adjusting the Integer-Values with the counter-variable... If you put the part between `Dim I` and `Next I` in your running code it will run as well. If you don't have the corrects objects in your `trmpnts`-Array it can't work.